# How can I train multi-networks on different GPUs in parallel with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to train 3 networks of different scales on 3 GPUs in paralle, then make an ensemble of these outputs. (with tensorflow)

Do I need to creat a graph and a corresponding session for each network? And what to do to make these sessions run concurrently rather than sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to creat a graph and a corresponding session for each network?

yes, since networks are not exactly same, separate graph and sessions are required to create.

> And what to do to make these sessions run concurrently rather than sequentially?

Suppose you have three training scripts `train_graph1.py`, `train_graph2.py`, `train_graph3.py`. you need to run all those scrips separately at the same time to run concurrently.

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0, train_graph1.py ....
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1, train_graph2.py ....
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2, train_graph3.py ....
```

Comment: I was trying to realize this in one single script. Maybe I am complicating it. Thanks a lot.